# Is it possible to grant SELECT on all future tables on any schema in a database?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to setup a Snowflake role that have access to all current and future tables in a given database:

```
create role if not exists MYROLE;
grant usage  on database                   MYDB to role MYROLE;
grant usage  on all    schemas in database MYDB to role MYROLE;
grant usage  on future schemas in database MYDB to role MYROLE;
grant select on all    tables  in database MYDB to role MYROLE;
grant select on future tables  in database MYDB to role MYROLE;
```

the `SHOW FUTURE GRANTS IN DATABASE MYDB;` confirms that the grants are there:

```
created_on  privilege   grant_on  name          grant_to  grantee_name  grant_option
...         USAGE       SCHEMA    MYDB.<SCHEMA> ROLE      MYROLE        false
...         SELECT      TABLE     MYDB.<TABLE>  ROLE      MYROLE        false
```

But they don't seem to have any effect.

I have a test schema `MYDB.TEST` and when I create tables with other role `OTHERROLE` the `MYROLE` can't "see" them.

```
use role accountadmin;
grant select on all    tables in database MYDB  to role MYROLE;
grant select on future tables in database MYDB  to role MYROLE;


use role otherrole;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE mydb.test.ruben_test AS (
    SELECT * FROM (values (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)) x(id,value)
);
select * from mydb.test.ruben_test; -- OTHERROLE can see table

use role myrole;
select * from mydb.test.ruben_test; -- SQL compilation error: Object 'MYDB.TEST.RUBEN_TEST' does not exist or not authorized.

use role accountadmin;
grant select on all tables in database MYDB  to role MYROLE;

use role myrole;
select * from mydb.test.ruben_test; -- now it can see it
```

The `grant select on future tables in database MYDB  to role MYROLE;` seems to be ignored.

If I use `grant select on future tables in schema MYDB.TEST  to role MYROLE;` then it will work, but I really don't want to have to write a grant for each schema in the db.

I'm opening a support case with Snowflake but in the meantime, is it possible to have a grant in all future table in database or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Most likely you have future grants at the schema level and that prevents the future grants at the database level from running as stated in [Precedence rule for future grants](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Precedence-rule-for-future-grants).

> As the future grants can be defined at both the database and schema
> level, the schema level grants always take precedence over the
> database level grants, the snowflake **will ignore the future grants
> applied at the database level**. Even if the user tries to change the
> future grants at the database level and one of the child schemas had a
> different future grant defined explicitly then this change will not be
> reflected at the schema level, it will be simply ignored without
> showing any error.